# Function on click with a href class in jquery

Tags: jquery

So for some reason I can't make jquery react on anchor click with class remove. The other function works just fine. I've tried changing it from class to id and it didn't work I've also tried changing id to the id of working function but it still didn't do anything.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($_POST['champion'] as $champion){
            echo $champion.'<br>';
        }
    }else{
?>
<a href="#" id="AddChampion">Add Champion</a>
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" method="POST">
    <div id="ChampionInput">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
    }
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    championNumber = 1;
    $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){
        $('#ChampionInput').append(
        '<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>\
         <br>\
         <input type="text" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
         <br>');
        championNumber++;
    });
    $('a.remove').on('click',function(){
        alert('test');

    });
});
```

Comment: just do $('#AddChampion').on('click', function(){})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a href associated with your anchor. You need to update your code to

```
$('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default handling
    .....
});

$("#ChampionInput").on('click', 'a.remove', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');

});
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2tiJf9u6kLR7lkiUuFT?p=preview

Comment: Well now it works even without preventDefault and I don't fully understand why do we need a selector and child-selector

Comment: In your case you can skip preventDefault(), however, let us say if href is http://www.stackoverflow.com, then, in that case you will need preventDefault(). Additionally, for selectors, one word is event-delegation. For details can refer to another answer on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22038965/1132354